# HTML's <style> tag in Fxml

Tags: css, fxml

Is it possible to write css rules inside FXML files? Something similar to the `<style>` tag (not the node attribute) in HTML.
EDITED: For example, I need to specify `list-cell` background color from within the fxml file. Afaik this can't be donde using the `style=""` node attribute.

Yes, I know it's better to use external css files, but I'm converting programmatically hundreds of windows from another language to fxml and have enough bunch of files.
It's a pitty I have to create a new file only to set `list-cell`'s background color.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Scenebuilder, you can write CSS styling inside fxml file for a particular node.

[image]

Comment: I edited my question to add an example. I need to change the cell's background color of a ListView.